# Expansion Files: Once the expansion files is downloaded start the Intent to next activity

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have the below code which will successfully download the expansion file, but i am not aware where to add my Intent so that once the `expansion file is downloaded` i can `start my activity.`

Please help with it.

```
try {
            Intent launchIntent = ExpansionFilesActivity.this.getIntent();
            Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent(ExpansionFilesActivity.this,
                ExpansionFilesActivity.this.getClass());
            intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

            if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
            for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories()) {
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
            }
            }

            // Build PendingIntent used to open this activity from
            // Notification
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ExpansionFilesActivity.this, 0,
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            // Request to start the download
            int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this, pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);

            if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
            // The DownloaderService has started downloading the
            // files,
            // show progress
            initializeDownloadUI();
            return;
            } // otherwise, download not needed so we fall through to
              // starting the movie
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot find own package! MAYDAY!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example on Android Developers guide has following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Check if expansion files are available before going any further
    if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {
        // Build an Intent to start this activity from the Notification
        Intent notifierIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.getClass());
        notifierIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        ...
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notifierIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Start the download service (if required)
        int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
                        pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);
        // If download has started, initialize this activity to show download progress
        if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
            // This is where you do set up to display the download progress (next step)
            ...
            return;
        } // If the download wasn't necessary, fall through to start the app
    }
    startApp(); // Expansion files are available, start the app
}
```

So first you look if it's available. If not download in service and when done give a notification to the user about the data is available.

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am exploring another design:

1. Call startApp() from within `public void onDownloadStateChanged(int newState)` when newstate == STATE_COMPLETED. For some reasons I am getting onDownloadState() invoked twice. I added a flag downloadStateCompleted to avoid double calling startApp().
2. Clear Notification on STATE_COMPLETED.

The experience for the user is perhaps better since after download is completed the app continues (into startApp()). BUT I  am not sure if such approach is against the way download library was designed and meant to be used. In the Expansion files docs I do not see any indication of calling startApp() from within `onDownloadStateChanged`.

Comment: how to clear the notifcation as i am not getting the notification Id at start?